When is $h=d\omega$
Given $h\in \Lambda^{k+1}(M)$, where $M$ is some manifold, how do we know that $h=d\omega$ for some $\omega\in \Lambda^k(M)$?
For example, consider $$h=h_1(x^1,x^2,x^3)\,dx^1\wedge dx^2+h_2(x^1,x^2,x^3)\,dx^3 \wedge dx^1+ h_3(x^1,x^2,x^3)\,dx^2\wedge dx^3\in\Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3) .$$ How do we know if this is $d\omega$ for some $\omega$, using $h_1,h_2,h_3$ only? The only method I can think of is to guess some $\omega$ and see if $d\omega=h$. But is there any general algorithm for determining if $h=d\omega$?

Probably this question is at least in spirit a duplicate, but I couldn't find an appropriate post to point to.
Suppose $h = d\omega$ for some $\omega$ (that is, that $h$ is exact); then $d h = d^2 \omega = 0$ (so $h$ is closed), so $dh = 0$ is a necessary condition.
More or less by definition, if the $i$th de Rham cohomology group $H^i(M)$ is trivial, then any closed $i$-form on $M$ is exact, that is, the necessary condition $dh = 0$ is also sufficient to guarantee that there is some $\omega$ such that $h = d\omega$. In the special case that $M$ is contractible (in particular if $M = \Bbb R^n$), the Poincaré Lemma gives that $H^i(\Bbb R^n) = 0$ for all $i \geq 1$.
Example ($M = \Bbb R^3$, $i = 2$) For convenience relabel the coordinates and coefficients in your example via
$$h = \alpha(x, y, z) \, dy \wedge dz + \beta(x, y, z) \, dz \wedge dx + \gamma(x, y, z) \, dx \wedge dy .$$
Then,
$$dh = (\alpha_x + \beta_y + \gamma_z) \,dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = 0 .$$
So, a necessary condition for the existence of an $\omega$ such that $h = d\omega$ is that
$$\alpha_x + \beta_y + \gamma_z = 0 ,$$
and the Poincaré Lemma implies that it is also sufficient.
Example Set $M := \Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$; we have $H^2(M) \cong \Bbb Z$, and the necessary condition $dh = 0$ is not sufficient. Indeed, the $2$-form $$\eta = \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac32}} (x \,dy \wedge dz + y \,dz \wedge dx + z \,dx \wedge dy)$$ satisfies $d\eta = 0$ but there is no $\omega$ such that $\eta = d\omega$: Suppose there were, and let $S^2 \subset M$ denote the unit sphere and $\iota : S^2 \hookrightarrow M$ the inclusion map. On the one hand, $\iota^* \eta$ is the volume form on $S^2$ induced by the standard volume form $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ on $M$, so $\int_{S^2} \iota^* \eta > 0$. On the other, Stokes' Theorem yields $$\int_{S^2} \iota^* \eta = \int_{S^2} \iota^* d\omega = \int_{S^2} d(\iota^* \omega) = \int_{\partial S^2} \iota^*\omega = \int_\emptyset \iota^* \omega = 0 ,$$ a contradiction.

I did find some similar posts and they used Poincare's lemma, which only applies to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your answer is more general.

There is a still more general version which basically applies to arbitrary manifolds, but it makes very heavy use of de Rham cohomology in combination of algebraic topology.
